# Android - Unit testing response handler class HttpException codes

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing

I'm writing a class to unit test my ResponseHandler class. Do I need to write a method for every possible HTTP error code that I am considering in the getErrorMessage function?
One for 400, 401, 403, 404, 503, etc?

**ResponseHandler.kt**

```
enum class ErrorCodes(val code: Int) {
    SocketTimeOut(-1),
    NoConnection(0)
}

class ResponseHandler {

    fun <T : Any> handleSuccess(data: T): Resource<T> {
        return Resource.success(data)
    }

    fun <T : Any> handleException(e: Exception): Resource<T> {
        return when (e) {
            is HttpException -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(e.code()), null)
            is SocketTimeoutException -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(ErrorCodes.SocketTimeOut.code), null)
            is IOException -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(ErrorCodes.NoConnection.code), null)
            else -> Resource.error(getErrorMessage(Int.MAX_VALUE), null)
        }
    }

    private fun getErrorMessage(code: Int): String {
        return when (code) {
            ErrorCodes.SocketTimeOut.code -> "Timeout"
            ErrorCodes.NoConnection.code -> "No Connection"
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST -> "Bad request"
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED -> "Unauthorized"
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_FORBIDDEN -> "Forbidden"
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND -> "Not found"
            HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAVAILABLE -> "Service Unavailable"
            else -> "Something went wrong"
        }
    }
}
```

**ResponseHandlerTest.kt**

```
    @Test
    fun `when exception is HttpException and code is 404 then return Not found error message`() {
        val httpException = HttpException(Response.error<List<StylesData>>(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND, mock()))
        val result = responseHandler.handleException<List<StylesData>>(httpException)
        assertEquals("Not found", result.message)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when exception is SocketTimeoutException then return Timeout error message`() {
        val socketTimeoutException = SocketTimeoutException()
        val result = responseHandler.handleException<List<StylesData>>(socketTimeoutException)
        assertEquals("Timeout", result.message)
    }

    @Test
    fun `when exception is IOException then return No connection error message`() {
        val ioException = IOException()
        val result = responseHandler.handleException<List<StylesData>>(ioException)
        assertEquals("No Connection", result.message)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, but I'd consider dividing that handler into specific cases with something like this:

```kotlin
@ControllerAdvice
class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(IOException::class)
    fun handle(ex: IOException?): ResponseEntity<String> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'd also move the error messages into a resource file, or into an enum, that's a better fit for this.

With it, you don't have to touch your code if you want to handle a new case and you also avoid an ever-increasing list of possible exceptions.

The relevant part of the docs are [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough I guess. That class is part of an Android app, so I can't use those annotations as they are Spring annotations. Anyway, if it still applies, I don't think I fully understand what you mean by dividing into specific cases. Do you mean dividing the handleException method in 3 methods, one for each exception type(IO, Http, SocketTO)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, I was sure that you were asking about [Spring] as I was filtering for [Spring] questions. :D